# Angular configuration in production with web and application servers

Tags: angular, nginx, wildfly

In development, I run an Angular app with `ng serve` and a proxy file to route to Wildfly port 8080:

```
{
  "/mysite/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8080",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

Now, I'm trying to find a way to deploy this in production with Nginx/Wildfly, where Nginx is configured on 10.0.0.5:80 and Wildfly on 10.0.0.4:8080.

What I found is that proxy files are only used in development environments, but I couldn't find a way to set up a similar routing in production. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Change the nginx.conf file to reroute the API calls.

```
    location /someurl/rest/ {
        proxy_pass http://10.0.0.4:8080/someurl2/;
    }
```